# Выполнение кода по нажатию кнопки "развернуть" С# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Новичок в C#... И не могу понять, как выполнить код по нажатию кнопки развернуть. Пытался кликать дважды в конструкторе, ничего... Как привязать эту кнопку к коду?

Comment: развернуть можно и без кнопки, вам надо код выполнить именно на кнопку или на разворачивание окна?

Comment: именно на кнопку, да.

Comment: то есть если просто 2 раза кликнуть на заголовок окна, то окно развернется, но ваш код отработать не должен, верно?

Comment: Упс, точно. Этот код скорее должен идти на вот это изменение размера. У меня может быть до 30 элементов на странице и когда переходим из маленького окна в большое, всё довольно долго перерисовывается. Хотелось бы на это изменение использовать сontrol.SuspendLayout();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы запустить какой то код на разворачивание окна, надо

1) Подписаться на событие `Resize`

2) В событии проверить состояние окна

Например

```
var f = new Form();
f.Resize += (sender, args) => {

    var form = sender as Form;

    if (form.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
    {       
        // Сюда вставляйте код, который должен выполняться по нажатию кнопки
        Console.WriteLine("maximized!");    
    }

};
f.ShowDialog();
```

Для подписки на событие в констуркторе надо 2 раза кликнуть здесь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И потом добавить нужный код тут

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не думаю, что автор вопроса создает форму вручную у себя в коде. Проще было бы для его понимания объяснить, как это сделать с помощью конструктора форм и окна свойств и событий

Comment: @AndreiKhotko это ваши предположения, они могут иметь связь с реальностью, а могут и не иметь. Если считаете, что мой ответ недостаточно информативен, то можете его подправить или написать свой - я не против. А пояснение того, как работает дизайнер форм и где там кнопочка подписки на событие, имхо, выходит за рамки вопроса, потому я бы не хотел тратить время на предположения. Если автору что то будет непонятно, он спросит, мы же на сайте для вопросов и ответов :)

Comment: Да, мои слова не претендуют на 100% истинность. Это всего лишь предположение, выдвинутое исходя из текста вопроса, где написано "Пытался кликать дважды в конструкторе, ничего...")

Comment: @AndreiKhotko хха, вы меня поймали, я, как обычно, прочитал вопрос по диагонали. Ок ок, я обновлю ответ :)

Comment: С меня ____ +1)